# PHP send email file not work -- Going Crazy -- cant find error

Tags: php, html, post

Ok I new to php , trying to make a simple send email form and for the life of me i cant find what I did wrong! The only error I am getting is that the property is undefined. but I used Postman to test my PHP file and it works fine https://www.getpostman.com/collections/9b8a8d084782d1184a10 , but when i run it from the site dabllc.net I get nothing

here is the sendemail.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status_good = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
);
$status_bad = array(
    'type'=>'$#!7',
    'message'=>'Thank you but not thanks. '
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'my@email.com';//replace with your email

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;
error_log($body . " " . $email_to);

$success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
if(!$success){
    echo json_encode($status_bad);
}
else{
    echo json_encode($status_good);
}

die;
```

and here is the form

```
<section id="contact-us">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">        
            <h2>Drop Your Message</h2>
            <p class="lead">Feel Free to contact us with any questions, and we will respond as fast as we can.</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
            <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
            <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/#contact-page-->
```

Errors -> http://pastebin.com/N6BB0nHj

Java script

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),

        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

please I have to be missing something small, Any help is appreciated. I dont want to have to rewrite this all.

Comment: so what does your ajax returns to you?

Comment: Could you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Here are the errors I am getting , its every variable   http://pastebin.com/N6BB0nHj

Comment: Can you also provide the javascript code please?

Answer (score 0):

Your error here lies in how you send your mail.

Since you do that via ajax with jQuery, anything you put down in HTML does not come into play here.

here is your code:

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),

            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
```

You have a listener there waiting for the form to be submitted. You actively disable the form itself from going on with submitting to put an ajax call in its place.

But your ajax call does not state that it is supposed to be a post request nor do you submit the values entered.

So here is how you do a post ajax call in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Maybe you want to read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

all you have to do is set "post" as method for the call and collect your form fields values to send them with it

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code does not send any data to sendemail.php. To fix it, use the code below:

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: ({
            name: $( '#name' ).val(),
            email: $( '#email' ).val(),
            phone: $( '#phone' ).val(),
            company: $( '#company' ).val(),
            subject: $( '#subject' ).val(),
            message: $( '#message' ).val()
        }),
        dataType: 'json',    
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Use this for the HTML:

```
<section id="contact-us">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">        
            <h2>Drop Your Message</h2>
            <p class="lead">Feel Free to contact us with any questions, and we will respond as fast as we can.</p>
        </div> 
        <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
            <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
            <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="company" class="form-control">
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject *</label>
                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div><!--/.row-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/#contact-page-->
```

Comment: why did you change the whole thing to use a get request? The way it is now, wouldn't it pose a security and a functional threat, not to escape form field values? Or is that taken care of by jquery somehow?

Comment: just saw it. was there a certain intention to go with get in the first version?

Comment: To answer your question, escaping with Javascript won't prevent any security threat since the code is executed on the machine of the user.

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of malformed input data. Just concatenating the strings should make injecting other values possible. But as long as those vars do not play a role in the code, there is no security issue, you are right there. On The other hand: what if there is an unescaped ampersand in the get request? That should at least endanger data integrity